# How in Castle.Windsor get object of component from IHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I created my custom facility for Castle.Windsor. 
In short. I mark some properties of component-classes with my custom attribute MyComponent. In this facility I subscribed on Kernel.ComponentRegistered. And on component registration I check if any of component's properties marked with the attribute. If yes, I use value of this property for component registration too.
The problem is how to get object of component itself when I have IHandler and string key of the object:

```
public class ComponentsSearcherFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
      Kernel.ComponentRegistered += OnComponentRegistered;
    }

    private void OnComponentRegistered(string key, IHandler handler)
    {
      var serviceProperties = handler.ComponentModel.Implementation
                                                    .GetProperties()
                                                    .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(MyComponentAttribute)))
                                                    .ToArray();

      if (!serviceProperties.Any())
        return;

      var componentObject = ?????;

      foreach (var serviceProperty in serviceProperties)
      {
        var interfaces = FindInterfacesRepresentedByProperty(serviceProperty.PropertyType);
        var instance = serviceProperty.GetValue(componentObject, null);
        Kernel.Register(Component.For(interfaces)
                                 .Instance(instance)
                                 .LifestyleSingleton());
      }
    }
  }
```

Temporarily I use such hack:

```
var componentObject = Kernel.Resolve(handler.ComponentModel.Services.First());
```

But although it works in general it will do it's job correctly only if I will follow some strict rules in classes declaration. And anyway it's bad.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve? This isn't how you'd normally handle nested dependencies, so if you explain your use case someone might know of a simpler solution.

Comment: @AndyLamb I'm trying to solve the following thing. I have some class which might be considered as sort of factory. It provides several services through properties. So what I want is to register components for these services taking their values as instances.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this approach is somewhat restrictive, it looks like the factory component has to be a singleton? I think a better approach would be to handle this in the code registering the top level component. You could encapsulate this in an extension method to maintain the fluent style of the registration and allow reuse. At the point you're registering the top level component you'd have access to the instance and could use reflection to get access to the properties generically.